# Teleporting a player from the overworld to the end

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to teleport a player from the overworld to the end?

Or a way of teleporting a player to a random enderman in the end?

Answer (score 19):

This is trivial in Minecraft 1.13:

```
/execute in the_end run tp <player> <location>
```

Comment: Note that this is not implemented in the Bedrock edition. A more restricted version of the /execute command does exist in the Bedrock edition and theoretically could be used to do something like this, but there's currently a bug where the /execute command disregards dimensions entirely. I've reported it here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-44104

Comment: How do I trigger the Ender dragon after tp?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the Ender Dragon"? Please ask a separate question, with many more details.

Comment: @Macil That bug is now reported to be fixed, but I can't figure out the corresponding Bedrock command to teleport... the above command gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You can spawn an end portal (like the one in the stronghold) one block above you:

```
 /setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:end_portal
```

Comment: This was definitely the quickest and most simple solution here, thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

### 1.13+:

The introduction of the new `execute in` has made this task pretty easy:

```
/execute in the_end run tp <player> <location>
```

See: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#in

### Before 1.13:

Not really. At least not directly. (something like `/tp @p 0 50 0 dimension:end` doesn't exist)

The only way would be to teleport them into an end-portal block (which you can create on any fixed position you'd like) and then to wherever you want (it takes some time to get to the end, so don't teleport them immediately).

Comment: Since you can make a portal block in a fixed position it is certainly possible to automate this.

Comment: of course it is possible to automate this, but you can't just do something like `/tp @p 0 20 0 dimension:end` or something, that was what i was trying to imply here. lemme quickly edit it to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

This solution I came up with, is building upon a possibility hinted in the answer of Plagiatus above.

1. Build an End Portal and use it.
2. In the overworld, set up a command block with `execute @p ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ end_portal`.

Alternative: If you want the portal to be immediately removed, you need a more complex setup. You need the following commands to be executed in this order:

2a) `execute @p ~ ~ ~ summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"PortalPoint",NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1}`

2b) `execute @e[name=PortalPoint,type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ end_portal`

2c) `execute @e[name=PortalPoint,type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air`

2d) `kill @e[name=PortalPoint,type=armor_stand]`

The condition `type=armor_stand` makes sure that the command doesn't have any side effects, even if a player or another entity is coincidentally named PortalPoint. (Don't look at me like that. Odds are that this happens.)

3. In the End, place a command block right below the obsidian layer, with `tp @a[r=4] x y z`, where x, y and z are the coordinates you want the player to be teleported to. The radius is picked so that it doesn't reach outside the spawn area, but still covers the player, even if he manages to move a bit before the command gets executed. You'll still want to put this in a repeat command block that's constantly active, so players spawning into the End get teleported immediately.
4. Make sure both the End Portal in the overworld and the spawn area in the End are not accessible during normal gameplay, so players can neither use the Portal for a shortcut to the end nor reach the spawn area again after they've been teleported away. (Because they would be teleported away again, which would be odd and, depending on what you're doing, might mess up things.) Actually, I'd assume you can remove the original entrance Portal safely.

This, of course, assumes that the End Portals placed by the command have the same spawn area as the End Portal you originally use. I'd strongly assume this is the case, but I've never actually used multiple different End Portals, so I have no actual experience how they interact. I didn't test because I'm still mainly using 1.8 because of Forge, so I didn't get the 1.9+ versions of my resourcepack yet. Trying it out in 1.8 would probably be pointless - I could adapt the entity IDs and such, but there's been so much changed about the End since that it might easily break or fix the setup between the versions.

Comment: Noiced my update had already been addressed above - it's the kind of thing you forget when coming back to an old answer after a while.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way. Not that I know of in vanilla Minecraft anyway. If you are in one dimension, in this case the Overworld, you cannot teleport to another dimension. If you enter a /tp @p ~ ~ ~, it will teleport you somewhere in the Overworld, and there's no tag or extra data that will specify the End.

Now, you ***could*** just run a command that spawns a portal exactly at the player's location, and hook up a command that will run as soon as the player is in the End, teleporting them to the desired coordinates. It would take a lot of calculating, but it could technically be done.

Comment: And I just realized that this is a _reeeaaaly_ old question.... I should probably check the date before I respond XD

Comment: Generally speaking answering old questions isn't a bad thing if you can add something new that the old answers don't already provide, or the old answers are outdated.

Comment: two years isn't really THAT old...

Answer (score -1):

You can teleport to a player who's in another dimension by being in Gamemode 3 and using your Itemsbar to teleport.

Comment: That is not what the question is asking for. The question wants Minecraft commands, and they want to teleport a player to a mob, not to another player. Please *read the question more carefully* before posting an answer.