# Cross-dimension teleportation using command block or datapack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to teleport a player in coordinates in another dimension? If not, is it possible using a datapack?

I'm using MultiVerse with 1.14 but their portals plugin is broken. I tried to use a command block but `mvtp @p otherworld` breaks, saying "can't find player @p". I assume Minecraft doesn't parse this since it's not a vanilla command.

Our goal is to teleport players after pushing a button on a block because we're a full survival server and don't allow teleports. Otherwise I *could* grant every permission to use `mvtp` directly.

Comment: Just a reminder that [Minecraft EULA does not allow you to ask for money to be able to use teleports](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1590522-minecraft-commercial-use) (Not saying is your case @BotskoNet)

Comment: This is problematic is plain vanilla too. I have a datapack with a warp system so players can use `/trigger warp set <number>` (where warp is a trigger enabled scoreboard) to activate an `execute in minecraft:overworld as @a[scores={warp=<number>}] run tp @s <some preset coords>` in a tick (looping) function. This, however, doesn't work properly outside of the overworld, as if I'm in the nether and set the warp to the code for my house, I end up at the same coords as my house but in the nether. Same situation in the end. If I run the execute function from chat, however, it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teleporting a player from the overworld to the end](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292340/teleporting-a-player-from-the-overworld-to-the-end)

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate. A Multiverse question shouldn't be duped with a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can teleport yourself to the end with this command

```
/execute in minecraft:the_end run tp @s <coordinates>
```

To the nether with this:

```
/execute in minecraft:the_nether run tp @s <coordinates>
```

Or to the overworld:

```
/execute in minecraft:overworld run tp @s <coordinates>
```

Comment: Would the `minecraft:worldname` syntax work for a second overworld (made with multiverse)?

Comment: I am not too familiar with mods, but I think it should work, though you would probably use something like `<mod name>:<world name>`

Comment: Yes it works with `minecraft:worldname`. Neat

Comment: I looked it up real quick and it looks like it is a mod that still uses vanilla minecraft dimensions, so in that case `minecraft:<world name>` does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still using Multiverse and their portals and it works just fine. However, Multiverse uses player names, not selectors. The goal of the portals isn't using commands or buttons, but actual *portals*

What you'll want to do with them is simple:

1. Create a small WorldEdit region that should serve as a portal. It can be on the ground to jump in or standing like a Nether portal to walk through.
2. While you have your desired region selected use the command `/mvp create <some distinct name>`. I'm usually naming them *sourceworldtargetworld* (e.g. *MainNether* for a Nether portal), so I don't have to look them up when I make changes.
3. Teleport yourself to the target world/location (`/mvtp` or a home or whatever else you have there) and connect the portal to that location: `/mvp modify dest here`. This will use your current location as the destination of that portal. You can as well use coords or even other portals as destination, but from my experience it is best to go with your current location.
4. Create a way home. You need another portal from the target world back to the source world. Just repeat steps 1 - 3 for a portal leading back to your home world.

Now your players don't have to use any commands or buttons and you don't have to worry about giving them permissions they shouldn't have. Players can simply walk or jump into the portals and they will do the rest for you. And if you want to allow or deny entry you can use Multiverse's permissions by granting/denying the permission `multiverse.portal.access.<portal name>`.