# How do I get back to the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I accidentally used `/spawnpoint` in the end in Creative Mode. Now, I keep respawning in the end, and my end portal won’t send me back to the overworld. What can I do to get back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teleporting a player from the overworld to the end](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292340/teleporting-a-player-from-the-overworld-to-the-end)

Comment: @pppery I think that is more about going *from* Overworld *to* End, but I'm not sure whether that is considered a duplicate. The concept is the same, but the situation is different. Do we still consider those duplicates?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Well, I do, at least, but I am known to have a broader-than-consensus view of what questions should be closed. The answer is functionally the same (just use `/execute in`) for both questions, which is good enough for me.

Comment: There are plenty of other questions closed as duplicate even if the answer isn't exactly the same, such as basically all 18 duplicates of [Command for spawning chest with CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272179/185203)

Comment: I feel the question is different enough to not be a duplicate, which is essentially a reversed case of the other question. The answer is similar, but I'm judging the duplicate based on the question, not the answer.

Comment: @MBorg Even ignoring the answer, the question can be distilled, in both cases to "how do I teleport from one dimension to another". You're inventing an arbitrary distinction to justify creating 6 questions (the number of dimensions in Minecraft choose 2) covering material than can adequately be covered by one question.

Comment: That makes me wonder if the other question should be editted to better reflect this broader scope and more clearly cover these 6 questions instead of the more narrow "Is there any way to teleport a player from the overworld to the end?" To one not so knowledgeable with the content (which seems to include that question asker), the two specific locations could potentially have signficance, whereas only those knowlegdeable who know the two specific locations do not have signifiance.

Answer (score 3):

## 1.13+ Only

Use `/execute in minecraft:overworld run teleport @s X Y Z`, replacing `X`, `Y`, and `Z` with the coordinates in the Overworld to teleport to (if you know them). Warning, this may spawn you inside a wall, and you will have to dig yourself out (easy in Creative, hard in Survival). If you don't want this issue, please use the 2nd answer below:

## Any Edition

Use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ end_portal` to set the block at your position to an end portal. You will immediately be registered inside it and be sent back to your world spawn in the Overworld.

Comment: You shouldn't answer duplicate questions, that just adds noise.

Comment: Also, the "end portal" suggestion is explicitly stated not to work in the question, since the user's spawn point has ended up in the end itself.

Comment: @pppery Ooh, good point. I never tested this, but maybe it *does* keep you in the End. I haven't tested it yet, I don't have access to MCJava at this time.

Comment: @pppery I *do* have access to Bedrock Edition, and it lets you back into the Overworld even with spawnpoint in the End. I interpreted the question as the fact that the End Portal is one way and that the OP doesn't see another one, not that the Exit Portal keeps the player in the End.

Answer (score 1):

## You can modify your player.dat file to get back to the overworld.

For this you'll need an NBT editor which can edit Minecraft's .dat files. I recommend NBTExplorer for this. It's available for both Windows and Mac.

Download and install NBTExplorer (or your editor of choice but I'm writing this with the assumption of NBTExplorer) and locate your player.dat file. This may be in the level.dat file of your world instead so if you're playing a singleplayer world check there first as it will override any player.dat files it finds. If it's in the level.dat file look for a tag called "Player" and expand it out. You're looking for a tag called "Dimension". Edit that to the overworld. (If your version has it with the word end typed out or minecraft:end or something similar, replace the word "end" with "overworld". If your version just has a number set it to 0 for the overworld.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting part quote from the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spawnpoint):

> If you set your spawnpoint in the End, you can't get out because the End Portal to return to the Overworld returns to your spawnpoint, and Nether Portals don't light in the End. However, you can use setblock to create a portal block which will take you to the Nether and you can return through the Nether Portal to go back to the Overworld.

This means, if you don't want to use `/execute in minecraft:overworld` (where there is the danger of spawning inside a block), just do the steps shown in the quote above.

1. Use the following command to summon a Nether Portal block.

   ```
   /setblock ~ ~ ~ nether_portal
   ```
2. You will immediately be registered as in the Nether Portal, and teleport to the Nether.
3. Light a nether portal normally or run the above command again and it will take you to the Overworld.