# How do I tell what dimension a player is in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I test for a player being in a world? I have 2 command blocks: the second one is conditional and relies on the first one to be correct for it to work. In the first command, I have this: `/execute if entity (player) in minecraft:the_nether run say test`, yet it says test every time even if the player is not in the nether.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a teleport command that does not work in the Nether?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226962/how-to-make-a-teleport-command-that-does-not-work-in-the-nether)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what your old command is actually doing.

```
execute                    
  if entity X              # If entity X exists...
  in minecraft:the_nether  # move the execution position to the Nether...
run say test               # and say a message
```

You'll need to use a similar approach to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226962) question and answer.

```
execute
  in minecraft:the_nether   # In The Nether...
  if entity @p[x=0]         # if there is any player in the dimension...
run say test                # then say a Message.
```